# using psycopg2 to insert pandas dataframe into postgres db errors on enum datatype

Tags: pandas, postgresql, dataframe, etl, psycopg2

When I try to insert a row from a pandas dataframe using psycopg2, I keep getting the following error. InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input value for enum enum_name: "column_name"

Does psycopg2 handle enum datatypes? When I changed the first enum column to varchar, the error went to the second enum column, so seems like there's something it doesn't like about the enum datatype. I've included my complete code below. Many thanks in advance!

```
# helper function for build_insert_query
def create_col_name_string(col_names):
    """
    input: takes list of column names
    output: returns string of all col names
    """
    return ','.join(col_names)

# helper function for insert_into_table
# builds query "INSERT INTO schema.table (col_names) VALUES(%s, %s...);"
def build_insert_query(schema, table, col_names):
    """
    input: takes schema and table name as strings as well as list of df column names
    output: returns formatted query
    """
    s = ','.join(['%s' for i in range(len(col_names))])
    query = "INSERT INTO %s.%s "% (schema, table)
    query = query + "(" + create_col_name_string(col_names) + ")" 
    query = query + "VALUES(" + s + ");"
    return query

# helper function for append_from_df_to_db
def insert_into_table(cur, schema, table, col_names):
    """
    inserts an individual record into table
    """
    query = build_insert_query(schema, table, col_names)
    
    # gets a string of col names
    vars_to_insert = create_col_name_string(col_names)
    
    cur.execute(query, tuple(col_names)) 

# loops over rows in dataframe and inserts into database    
def append_from_df_to_db(cur, df, schema, table, col_names):    
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        insert_into_table(cur, schema, table, col_names)
```

Comment: To me `cur.execute(query, tuple(col_names))` looks like it is inserting using the column names as the column values.

Comment: FYI, it is not the `enum` type causing the issue. Also use [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) to do the dynamic SQL building.  The string interpolation you are doing now is a short cut to SQL injection. See the **Warning** in [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries): *The problem with the query parameters*

Comment: Thanks Adrian! Both your comments were very helpful. I rebuilt the query.

Comment: So did it work?  If it did, you should create an answer with the working code, so anyone coming across this later can see what worked.